# Sending response to ajax using tornado

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, tornado

I have a web form which sends a ajax post request to tornado server containing form data but the response by

```
self.write(message)
```

is just being  displayed in the browser instead of js handling it.How can i correct this?

```
class NewHandler(BaseHandler):
@tornado.web.authenticated
def post(self):
    message = {
            "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "from": self.current_user["name"],
            "body": self.get_argument("body"),
            }

    message["html"] = tornado.escape.to_basestring(self.render_string("message.html", message=message))
    self.write(message)
    messages.new([message])
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
document.session = $('#session').val();


$('#messageform').submit(function(event) {
    var formdata = $('#messageform').formData();
    var button = $('#messageform').find("input[type=submit]");
    button.prop("disabled", true);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/new',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        success: function(response){
            messageBox.show(eval("("+response+")");
            button.prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
};

var messageBox = {
show: function(message){
    var content = $(message.html);

    $("#inbox").append(content);

}
```

Comment: Try calling event.preventDefault(); right before var formdata = $('#messageform').formData();

Answer (score 0):

Try to raise StopIteration just after self.write() method:

```
self.write(somedata)
raise StopIteration
```